# map-like serialization w/ data values as keys

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I need to serialize this:

```
List<Event>
```

where the Event class is:

```
public class Event {
  public int id;
  public String foo;
  public String bar;
}
```

into JSON of this form:

```
{
  "123":{"foo":"...","bar":"..."},
  "345":{"foo":"...","bar":"..."}
}
```

Taking the "id" property out of Event and storing a Map would do the trick, but I need to support duplicate IDs.

Is there an annotation I can put on the "id" property to cause Jackson to treat it as a key, with the rest of the object as the associated value?

Comment: You MUST accept your answers more often

Answer (score 0):

With your current structure of ID as the key, I'm not sure having duplicate IDs is possible in the JSON spec.  Maybe if you had arrays with the IDs.  I think you need to re-evaluate your desired JSON output.

Comment: I agree.  The structure of the JSON is not ideal.  Unfortunately it's out of my control.  The server expects that particular format.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `IdentityHashMap`, so you could use different instances of string containing same value and have this result:

```
{"1":{"foo":"foo1","bar":"bar"},"2":{"foo":"foo2.1","bar":"bar"},"3":{"foo":"foo2","bar":"baz"},"2":{"foo":"foo2","bar":"baz"}}
```

that you can have executing this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.IdentityHashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonTest {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

        IdentityHashMap<String, Event> ihm = new IdentityHashMap<String, Event>();

        List<Event> list = Arrays.asList( //
                new Event(1, "foo1", "bar"), //
                new Event(2, "foo2", "baz"), //
                new Event(2, "foo2.1", "bar"), //
                new Event(3, "foo2", "baz") //
                );

        for (Event e : list) {
            ihm.put(String.valueOf(e.id), e);
        }

        System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(ihm));
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "id" })
    public static class Event {
        public int id;
        public String foo;
        public String bar;

        public Event(final int id, final String foo, final String bar) {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.foo = foo;
            this.bar = bar;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I ended up simply doing the JSON encoding "by hand" and annotating the method with @JsonValue.  This is running on Android, so I used Android's static JSONOBject.quote() method to escape the strings.

Comment: I can see how `@JsonValue` works, but there is no need to quote anything -- just return POJO or `Map` with "correct" structure, and serializer will recursively handle it.